# Nested for loop on Terraform with reference from another resource

Tags: loops, object, templates, terraform, nested

I have a Terraform module that receives a variable called "service_accounts_objects". Each object receives a service account string to create a new service account and a list of strings with roles that this SA will receive. On the module side, I could create the Service Accounts, but now I don't know how to reference the SA member generated by the first resource to apply the correct roles on it.
I know I can reference google_service_account.service_account with:

```
for_each = google_service_account.service_account
```

but this takes my only for-each loop that I can use on this resource

Module code:

```
module "iam" {
  source  = "../../modules/iam"
  project = var.project
  service_accounts_objects = [
    {
      service_account = "service-${var.project_short}-tl"
      roles = [
        "roles/run.invoker",
        "roles/cloudsql.client",
        "roles/cloudsql.instanceUser",
        "roles/pubsub.publisher"
      ]
    },
    {
      service_account = "service-${var.project_short}-template"
      roles = [
        "roles/cloudsql.client",
        "roles/cloudsql.instanceUser",
        "roles/pubsub.publisher"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  for_each = {
    for index, sa in var.service_accounts_objects:
      sa.service_account => sa
  }
  project = var.project
  account_id = each.value.service_account
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "member" {
  for_each = {
    for i, role in var.service_accounts_objects: 
      role.roles => role
    for j, members in google_service_account.service_account:
      members.member => members
  }
  member  = each.value.member
  project = var.project
  role    = each.value.role
}
```

I'm a noob on Terraform and I don't know if that's even possible

EDIT:
Couldn't find a way, so I created a module and called it for every service account I wanted to create.

Module call:

```
module "iam-service-tl" {
  source  = "../../modules/iam"
  project = var.project
  service_account_object = {
    service_account = "sa-service-tl"
    roles = [
      "roles/run.invoker",
      "roles/cloudsql.client",
      "roles/cloudsql.instanceUser",
      "roles/pubsub.publisher"
    ]
  }
}
```

Variables and module resources:

```
variable "project" {}
variable "service_account_object" {
  description = "The list of service accounts to be created."
  type = object(
    {
      service_account = string
      roles           = list(string)
    }
  )
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  project    = var.project
  account_id = var.service_account_object.service_account
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "member" {
  member  = google_service_account.service_account.member
  project = var.project
  for_each = toset(var.service_account_object.roles)
  role = each.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by the 'first service' you mean GCP service account, it should be accessible by `google_service_account.service_account[X]`, where `X` is whatever you have under `service_accounts_objects.[].service_account` property

Just a general tip, if you're not sure what references objects have try running `terraform state list` to list them all.